# Name of this design pattern?

Tags: oop, qt, design-patterns

I'm trying to figure out the name behind this design pattern. Basically, you have some arbitrary data that needs to be processed, and any arbitrary number of "handler" objects that may be capable of handling the data. The data gets passed to these handlers until something processes it.

For example, in Qt, QImage reads images via QImageReader. QImageReader queries QImageIOHandler objects to see if the given file format can be read by that QImageIOHandler. If so, it uses that handler to read the image.

Is there a name for this delegation of responsibility?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)